# Read External Properties correctly

Tags: maven, spring-boot

How can i ccr.read.clientSecret value from override.properties
I am on windows 10
I am trying to run the Spring Boot app using command line

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dspring.config.location=file:D:/myname/Properties/override.properties myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My jar file has application.properties

```
#tomcat port
server.port=8081

#Spring Batch App
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.profiles.active=

#JPA Properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernae.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

My application-local.properties is

```
accr.read.clientId=JOHN
accr.read.clientSecret=
accr.read.grantType=client_credentials
accr.read.scope=scope1


# Database settings
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@devdb.in.world:1522/DEV01
spring.datasource.username=USER$NAME
spring.datasource.password=password123
```

override.properties

```
ccr.read.clientSecret=passwordisthis
```

When i am executing the first command to run spring boot application
I am gettin the below error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-03 15:18:43.675 ERROR 14828 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles local are currently active).
```

Comment: did you check if OracleDriver is in classpath , also check driver package as well, try changing to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: When using `spring.config.location` then that will be the file that gets loaded as the configuration it will skip all other files. Instead use `spring.config.additional-location` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to run your application like this

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --ccr.read.clientSecret=passwordisthis
```

The exception you are seeing is because you specified a location that has only your override properties. You should include multiple locations (in your case the classpath too) so spring knows where to look.

Example :

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:D:/myname/Properties/override.properties,classpath:/ myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It is important to notice that the approach of using simultaneously a profile and an override properties file might lead to problems (because when setting an active profile, the properties on the application-${profile}.properties will have the highest priority and will not be overridden if they exist).

Full documentation of spring external properties https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and annotate a class with `@PropertySource` like this:

```
@PropertySource("${my.config.location}")
@Component
public class Config {

    @Value("${ccr.read.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }

    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Config{" +
                "clientSecret='" + clientSecret + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

You can have `@PropertySource` also on a configuration class.

Now run the application with `-Dmy.config.location=file:D:/myname/Properties/override.properties` variable. Notice that I changed the variable name, for reason described below.

What's wrong with your approach: `-Dspring.config.location` points to the `application.properties` file location but you already have one in the classpath. By overwriting the `application.properties` file location, you replace the existent one from classpath with `...\override.properties` which is not a directory.

> By default Spring Boot tries to load application.properties (or
>   application.yml) from the following locations:
>   classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/. Of course, we
>   may override it. You can change the name of main configuration file by
>   setting environment property spring.config.name or just change the
>   whole searching path by setting property **spring.config.location**. It
>   can contains names of directories, as well as file paths.

See [this post](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/a-magic-around-spring-boot-externalized-configuration/) for further details.

Comment: i am getting the below error after makin  the changes.`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]`

Comment: i have created Config  class.Left my ovverride.properties and  application-local.properties  same only.

Answer (score 0):

According to this rule "If you have specified any files in spring.config.location, profile-specific variants of those
files are not considered. Use directories in spring.config.location if you want to also use
profile-specific properties" profile-specific file will not be considered use location instead.